# Java Timezone issue with LocalDate not showing correct date

Tags: java, timezone, localdate, zoneid

I'm currently based in Europe/London

I am trying to get the current day in Samoa, which is 27 July with the following code:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Samoa"));
```

However for some reason this outputs as:

```
2023-07-26
```

It's currently 16:47, 26 July in London, and 4:47, 27 July in Samoa.

I don't understand why I'm getting the 26 as output if Im using Samoas zoneId.

Comment: You're wrong, it is currently 26 July 2023 04:54 in Samoa, while it is 26 July 2023 16:54 in London. See https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/american-samoa. It has UTC -11, not UTC +11

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Samoa and American Samoa are not the same country: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/samoa

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Sure, but Pacific/Samoa refers to American Samoa these days (in the past it was also for Samoa). The one for Samoa is Pacific/Apia

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS You're right, I focused too much on the time zone and not the country :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Pacific/Samoa is no longer the time zone for Samoa, but only the time zone for American Samoa. And in American Samoa, it is currently 05:07 on the 26th of July (18:07 on the 26th of July Europe/Amsterdam).

A few years ago (in 2011), Samoa transited the international dateline resulting in a new time zone, and you need to use the time zone Pacific/Apia:

```
jshell> LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Apia"))
$3 ==> 2023-07-27
jshell> LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Apia"))
$4 ==> 2023-07-27T05:07:08.188250
```

Comment: As a quick sidenote one can always print the rules of the ZoneIds to check what their actual offset is. eG `ZoneId.of("Pacific/Samoa").getRules()` will show `currentStandardOffset=-11:00` while the ZoneId `ZoneId.of("Pacific/Apia").getRules()` will show `currentStandardOffset=+13:00`.  Knowing the actual offset values is certainly a useful tool when debugging.

Answer (score -1):

According to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcs/tag-ref/MISC/TimeZones.html), you'll want to use a `ZoneId` of `Pacific/Pago_Pago` to get Samoan time.

Edit: As Jon corrected below; the doc I've linked to is old and `Pacific/Samoa` is an acceptable ID. Leaving this here as reference.

Comment: That looks like it's a pretty old table (2015 if https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcs/tag-ref/index.html is to be believed). `Pacific/Samoa` is a perfectly good time zone ID. Mark Rotteveel's comment is a more appropriate response IMO.

Comment: Pacific/Pago_Pago is an alias for Pacific/Samoa, or at least it is also 26 July there.